# Merge on range between two columns

Tags: python, datetime, merge, data-science

I have a table of records with a position "stand" and a column timestamp or "datetime". I need to append this table with information on "acreg" and "flight".

The table with records (`df_hvd`) has the following columns of interest:

| datetime | stand | reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 022-08-08 02:55:15 | D02 | Technical |

I have a table with all flights (arriving and departing movements), and the corresponding start and end time of each movement. Based on the movement and stand, I want to retrieve the correct "acreg" and "flight". This source data looks like (`df_events`):

| acreg | flight | movement_type | start_datetime | end_datetime | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PHTFM | OR1072 | AR-PK | 2022-08-08 02:24:44 | 2022-08-08 04:07:00 | D02 |
| PHTFM | OR377 | PK-DP | 2022-08-08 12:15:00 | 2022-08-08 14:42:22 | D07 |

Note that the timestamp of the first table falls between the start and end times in the second table. I somehow need to find a way to performa a merge that understands that the record of interest corresponds to the first movement in the source data.

I tried to built a loop, but it is far too slow and it has some key errors:

```
for r in df_hvd.index: 
    for e in df_temp.index: 
        if df_hvd.at[r, "Positie"] == df_temp.at[r, "stand"]:
            if df_hvd.at[r, "datetime"] <= df_temp.at[e, "end_datetime"] and df_hvd.at[r, "datetime"] >= df_temp.at[e, "start_datetime"]: 
                print(df_temp.at[r, "acreg"])
```

This also didn't work:

```
for e in df_temp.index: 
    stand = df_temp.at[e, "stand"]
    start = df_temp.at[e, "start_datetime"]
    end = df_temp.at[e, "end_datetime"]
    acreg = df_temp.at[e, "acreg"]
    
    df_hvd.loc[(df_hvd["datetime"] <= end) & (df_hvd["datetime"] >= start) & (df_hvd["Positie"] == stand), 'acreg'] = acreg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below merging:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_hvd, df_events, how='inner', left_on=['stand'], right_on=['position'])
merged_df = merged_df[(merged_df['datetime'] >= merged_df['start_datetime']) & (merged_df['datetime'] <= merged_df['end_datetime'])]
```

To avoid duplicates:

```
df_hvd['merged'] = False  
for r in df_hvd.index:
    stand = df_hvd.at[r, 'stand']
    timestamp = df_hvd.at[r, 'datetime']
    mask = (df_temp['position'] == stand) & (df_temp['start_datetime'] <= timestamp) & (df_temp['end_datetime'] >= timestamp)
    if not mask.any():
        continue  
    matching_flights = df_temp.loc[mask]
    for i, flight in matching_flights.iterrows():
        if flight['merged']:
            continue 
        df_hvd.at[r, 'acreg'] = flight['acreg']
        df_hvd.at[r, 'flight'] = flight['flight']
        flight['merged'] = True
        df_temp.at[i, 'merged'] = True
```

Comment: thanks that works! However, it seems that there are a lot of overlapping flights for the same "acreg". Is it possible to make each merge happen only once? I know have a lot of duplicate rows.

Comment: I edit my answer and added code to avoid duplicates. Let me know if this work or run into any issue